# How to append to an existing array value in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

I need to combine two PHP associative array values into one.
Consider this code:

```
$period['duration'] = "35";
$period['timeunit'] = "Years";

print_r($period);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [duration] => 35
    [timeunit] => Years
)
```

But what I need to end up with is just:

```
Array
(
    [duration] => 35 Years
)
```

I've searched the documentation for this but can only find how to merge whole arrays or append new keys to the array etc.

This is because I have a HTML form that has a text field for the number, then a drop down for the unit (e.g years, months etc.)

I can't see a plain HTML way of combining two separate input fields before submitting via POST, otherwise I'd do that.  I'm assuming PHP processing the post values afterwards is preferable to pre-processing with javascript.

Comment: @mickmackusa That question is completely different to mine.  It's about concatenating two strings together, not appending to existing values in an array.

Comment: `$period['duration']` is a string.  `$period['timeunit']` is a string.

Comment: `$period['duration'] .= ' ' . array_pop($period);`  https://3v4l.org/5TPm8

Comment: Ah, I see.  You can append using .= like with a regular string.  I always thought of arrays as being different, but I guess each value is the same as a regular string.  Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't create a new array with the data that you want

```
$period['duration'] = "35";
$period['timeunit'] = "Years";
print_r($period);
$period2 = ['duration' => $period['duration'] . ' ' . $period['timeunit']];
//another way will be but if you have more elements not work like you expected
$period2['duration'] = implode(' ', $period);
```

Comment: Thanks @Emiliano !  That's one way round it, though I've decided to rethink my approach and perhaps have a third field that has the concatenated data instead.

Answer (score 0):

Two methods for you:

1. Use dot to concatenate duration, space and timeunit, then remove timeunit from array:

```php
$period['duration'] .= " " . $period['timeunit'];
unset($period['timeunit']);
```

2. Use [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), But this way only works if your array has only 2 elements:

```php
$duration = implode(" ", $period);
$period = ['duration' => $duration];
```

Comment: Thanks @Calos  The first option is on the right lines, but it overwrites all other values in the array...  (lets say I have 50 others unrelated to these two)..
It should be:  $period['duration'] => $duration;
However, when I reload the values from the DB, it's obviously displaying wrong, so I actually need to totally rethink my approach after all!  (I think I'll have a third array value with the concatenated data).   Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Okay, while this question is marked duplicated, I modified the first method based on your description, I hope to help you.

Comment: Amazing!  Thanks, Calos.